# I am having problems with double-quotes when updating a value in a json file

Tags: json, parsing, key, updating

I am reading a json file that's a configuration file for a 3D slicer engine. I am using the following code (summarized, not complete)

```
Dim json As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\tmp\theme.json")

Dim jsonObj As Object = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)
```

I am reading a specific value from the file and putting the value (RGB values) into a text box and showing the found color in a picturebox:

```
Dim read = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)

col = read.Item("colors")("layerview_inset_0").ToString
        
col = Replace(col, "[", "")
        
col = Replace(col, "]", "")
        
col = Trim(col)
        
TextBox1.Text = Trim(Replace(col, " ", ""))
        
cols = Split(col, ",")
        
PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(cols(0), cols(1), cols(2))
```

This all works fine.

What I do next is load a colorpicker by clicking on the picturebox and selecting a different color :

```
With ColorDialog1
            
'Get the current color from the picturebox
            
.Color = ColorDialog1.Color
            
If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                
Me.PictureBox1.BackColor = .Color
                
TextBox1.Text = .Color.R.ToString & "," & .Color.G.ToString & "," & .Color.B.ToString & "," & "255"
                
code = "[" & .Color.R.ToString & "," & .Color.G.ToString & "," & .Color.B.ToString & "," & "255" & "]"
            
End If
        
End With
```

This creates a string value (code) that I then use to replace the key in the file:

```
jsonObj("colors")("layerview_inset_0") = code
```

and then write back the updated file

```
Dim output As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)

File.WriteAllText("C:\tmp\theme.json", output)
```

This also works fine but the value inserted is wrapped in double quotes.

The Original Value in the file is like this :

```
 "layerview_inset_0": [ 
      255,
      255,
      255,
      255
      ],
```

But after my update it is :

```
 "layerview_inset_0": "[0,0,160,255]",
```

This causes the program to fail when loading the file.
If I remove the double-quotes it works OK.
I haven't worked with json files before and it has taken ages to get this far. How can I add the data I need into the json file and NOT have it wrapped in double-quotes?
I expect it's because I am inserting the value as a string but I don't know any other way to do it as I need to make sure I also add the [ and ] as well as each of the RGB values like the original format.

Everything works well except the addition of the double-quotes around the new value in the file, but how do I add this data to the file without it happening?
I would appreciate any guidance on this, bearing in mind that this is my first attempt at parsing a json file and replacing a key value, so please be kind. I'm probably doing it all wrong!